# Simple Concurrent Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I've done a fair amount of research over the past few days, but I'm not sure what the current best practice is for concurrent Core Data.  The most relevant post seems to be this [blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/), but in light of [this analysis](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout) about the performance of different concurrency methods, it seems that the modern way with parent contexts might not be the best.  Also, [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723) from Apple doesn't implement the best practice mentioned in [Apple's own concurrency guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/initWithConcurrencyType%3a) that recommends NOT using the default NSConfinementConcurrencyType.

In light of all of this, what is the simplest and best way to implement concurrency with Core Data?  All I need is a background thread the do some long writes to Core Data without hanging up the UI. Code examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it really depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

"long writes" will hang your UI no matter the architecture you implement.
A write operation lock the DB file in the OS level and the sqlite engine level (if you use this kind of store), all pending read operations will have to wait for the write to end before they complete.
One of the most used optimisation methods is segmenting the database "load" process with multiple save operations (you shouldn't mind as this happen in the background).

So, to answer the question:
The simplest way for you, would probably be to use the architecture described in the blog post you mentioned (parent-child hierarchy). if you notice that this cause to much "stutter" for your UI, try to optimise your data load process or try a different architecture.
use instruments to find "bottle necks" in your application execution.

CodeData has "quirks"/bugs in every architecture that I know, and you will find them gradually, depending on your use of it.

Comment: Under what circumstances will a read have to wait for writes to complete?  I assumed that having two contexts, one for reading and one for writing would solve that problem (except for maybe when the changes are merged).  Also, can you go into a little more detail on what kind of "quirks" you've found?

Comment: A write operation lock the persistent store coordinator (in CoreData I noticed that even read operations lock the PSC). this mean that no other operation (from any context) may hit the store through that PSC. also, a write operation will lock the file in the SQLite engine level (to prevent partial write, and then a read of corrupted data before a write ends). finally, a write operation lock the file in the OS level from the same reason.

Comment: As for the "quirks"/bugs ... mostly things during merge of changes between contexts and the reaction of the fetched results controller to them. or un-trappable exceptions in parent-child architecture (related to access of a deleted object in a to-many relationship). there are more, but it is an article within itself ...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to go with the parent/child context pattern. In the light of the sparse details you give (e.g. number of records, total volume of data, latency of delivery, etc). this seems to be the most flexible and proven solution that can also accommodate very large datasets.

Contrary to other claims, you can have a smoothly operating UI regardless of how long the "writes" are to your database. Obviously, that is what background threads are for. The mechanism to keep the UI fluid is through so-called notifications about data change. You can react to these gracefully without disturbing the user experience.

Your remark about `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is correct. As stated in your source, it is there for backward compatibility, so you can just forget about it. Obviously, for concurrency you want to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` when creating your context.

Comment: A long save (one that take seconds) is locking the PSC, any fetch/fault fired during the time when the PSC is locked will wait for the save to complete ==> UI will stutter if it try to fetch un-cached data. segmenting the data load to smaller chunks will reduce the lock time of the PSC and UI stutter. using WAL might also help.